# What is the implicit decay of char* arrays?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, array-pointer

As a newbie, I'm solving a problem from K&R's pointers chapter and was confused with some aspects of character pointers, and passing an array of type char* as a function parameter.

Char array decay I understand

Ex:

```
    void main( )
    {
        char a[ ] = "Howdy";

        tryMe(a);
    }
```

so here function parameter passed is **&a[0]**

```
    void tryMe( char* s  )
    {
        printf("value I need: %c \n", *s);
    }
```

So this would be **s = &a[0];**

Now using the above understanding, I tried to do the same for an array of type char*. with the same function tryMe(char*)

Ex::

```
    char a[ ] = "Howdy";
    char b[ ] = "Doodie";

    char* a1 = a;
    char* b1 = b;

    char* AP[ ] = { a1 , b1 };

    //  now to pass array AP into the function tryMe::

   tryMe(AP);
```

This is where I get a warning saying:

> > warning: passing argument 1 of ‘tryMe’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Im not sure what is going on, but I did get it working fine by doing the following thing:

changing function defintion from

> > tryMe(char*)
> > to
> > tryMe(char**)

and this works fine.

The other solution that works is:

Function definition remains same::

> > void tryMe(char*)

but while passing the function parameter it goes as follows::

```
    void tryMe( char* s[ ]  )
    {
       ;
    }
```

Though these above changes work as I want them to, I'm lost as to why are they working

I would really appreciate any guidance on these.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between `char *` and `char []` is?

Comment: May want to checkout: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/

Comment: Yes, `char*` and `char**` are two different things. One is a pointer to (an array of) characters, the other is a pointer to a pointer to (an array of) characters.

Comment: You have an exceptionally peculiar habit of spacing things out here for no reason. It's traditionally `char[]`, no spaces, or like `char x[]`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. my end goal is to swap a1 with b1. So when im calling AP, does the compiler implicity consider it to be &AP[0] ??

Comment: @tadman noobAlert

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* AP[ ] = { a1 , b1 };` defines `AP` to be an array containing two `char *`. So `AP` is **not** an array of `char`. In `tryMe(AP);`, the array `AP` is converted to a pointer to its first element, `&AP[0]`. Since its first element is a `char *`, the pointer to it has type `char **`.

A `char **` is unsuitable to pass as an argument for a parameter of type `char *`, so the compiler complains.

To pass one of the arrays (by pointer to its first element), you could use `tryMe(AP[0])` or `tryMe(AP[1])`.

If you change the function definition to have a parameter of type `char **`, then, say `char **x`, when you pass `AP`, the function will receive a pointer to the first element of `AP`. To get to the characters in the relevant array, it will have to dereference the pointer multiple times: `x` is a pointer to a `char *`, `*x` is the `char *`, and `**x` is a character.

Alternately, `x` is a pointer to the first element of the array, `x[0]` and `x[1]` are the `char *` elements in that array, `x[0][0]` is the first character of the string pointed to by the first `char *`, `x[1][4]` is the fourth character of the string pointed to by the second `char *`, and so on.